# Can I change the time using console?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Waiting is tough. Can I just change the time/date using the console?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29) doesn't seem to have anything listed for it, but you can use:

```
set timescale to #
```

Where # is the rate at which time passes. 20 is default, 1 is realtime. You can set it to get to the hour you want then set it back.

**Edit:** It should be noted that setting `timescale` to either [1 or 0 has been known to cause issues](http://j-u-i-c-e.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Change-the-Timescale-in-Skyrim). 2 seems to be the lowest safe value. At 0, fast traveling causes load issues, and at 1 there can be delays in AI processing. Both, however, have the effect of `1 minute real = 1 minute skyrim` or `1 minute real = 0 minute skyrim`.

Comment: Perhaps this should be a separate question:  Would `0` freeze time?

Comment: @Iszi Updated with an answer to that question. In short, it causes a lot of issues.

Comment: Thank for the answer :) Will these issues continue to be a bother once I revert the time scale to default? Or will changing the time scale once have a cascading effect for the rest of my character's life?

Comment: Should be only as long as you have it changed. That seems to be what all the posts have been saying at least.

Comment: Thank you Ktash - now I type `set timescale to 12000`, watch as the sun rises and sets rapidly twice, revert to `set timescale to 20`, and walk in to see that merchants have their inventory reset :)

Answer (score 1):

`set gamehour to #`

I like to use "set gamehour to 10" and then wait 1 hour, all the stores are then open.

Answer (score 0):

Or this maybe this was what your where looking for:

Console command: `sgtm <#>`

Source: [elderscrolls.wikia.com](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com)

Console return value/text : "Global Time Multiplier >> #". # is at least double (variable type).