# Is it possible to adjust game speed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I know that you can adjust the speed of the passage of time and also your walk speed, but I want to adjust the actual game speed itself.  Basically, I want the entire game to run as if it were in fast forward mode.  This means everything speeds up (character speed, passage of time, NPC movement, enemy movement, etc).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I change the time using console?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/50654/can-i-change-the-time-using-console)

Comment: @ Unionhawk, it's not a duplicate - he is not asking "How to change the date/time", he is asking how to make the game speed faster.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? That would make the game unplayable.

Comment: @kotekzot How?  If I increase it by a factor of 1.5, it will be fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Console command: **set timescale to <#>**

> Set the rate at which time passes (20 is the default, 1 is realtime)

source: [elderscrolls.wikia.com](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Console_Commands_%28Skyrim%29)

Or this maybe this was what your where looking for:

Consol command: **sgtm <#>**

> set global time multiplier

source: [youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MoytKiBQwyw)

Comment: sgtm!  I just confirmed that it does exactly what I want.

Comment: @oscilatingcretin oops, you're right. Apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Print Screen</kbd> to increase the in-game speed of everything; even movement and time. This only works on PC of course. No need for consoles or mods!

Comment: I looked this up, and while I don't see any official sources, there are a lot of people claiming this is an actual thing. Do you have a source to back it up?

Comment: does indeed work :) 2x the game is